# Error declaring a variable as Outlook.MailItem in Excel VBA: user defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I get

> compile error: user defined type not defined.

The yellow highlight is for this line:

```vb
Public Function SendMessage(strSubject, strRecip, strMsg, strAttachment) As Boolean
```

Blue highlight for this line:

```vb
Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function SendMessage(strSubject, strRecip, strMsg, strAttachment) As Boolean

Dim mOutlookApp As Object
Dim mNameSpace As Object
Set mOutlookApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.application")
Set mNameSpace = mOutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim mFolder As Object
Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set mItem = mOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
mItem.To = "Americas"
mItem.CC = strRecip
mItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Jordan"
mItem.Subject = strSubject
mItem.Body = strMsg
mItem.Attachments.Add strAttachment

mItem.Display
mItem.Recipients.ResolveAll

End Function


Sub Summarydraft()
Dim result As Boolean

Dim strRecip As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strAttachment As String

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Worksheets("Control").Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range, fullrng As Range
Set fullrng = Worksheets("Control").Range("N3:N" & LastRow)
Dim recip As String

    For Each rng In fullrng
        recip = recip & "; " & rng.Value
    Next
    
    strRecip = recip
    strSubject = Worksheets("Control").Range("G14")
    strMsg = Worksheets("Control").Range("G17")
    strAttachment = Worksheets("Control").Range("G20")
    result = SendMessage(strSubject, strRecip, strMsg, strAttachment)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try  "Set mItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)" instead of "Set mItem = mOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)" ?

Answer (score 1):

Either change the line

```
Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem
```

to

```
Dim mItem As Object
```

Or add Outlook as a reference in your VBA project.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting a property is read only on the strAttachment part of the code.

Comment: On the `mItem.Attachments.Add` line?

Comment: I had this error come up on one computer and it was your answer that reminded me to make sure the libraries were referenced.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Outlook COM reference to your VBA project if you want to declare Outlook types in the code.

In the code you used the late binding technology. This technology uses either the Visual Basic `GetObject` function or the `CreateObject` function to initialize Outlook.

To use early binding, you first need to set a reference to the Outlook object library. Use the Reference command on the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) `Tools` menu to set a reference to Microsoft `Outlook xx.x Object Library`, where `xx.x` represents the version of Outlook that you are working with. You can then use the following syntax to start an Outlook session.

```
Dim objOL as Outlook.Application 
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
```

Read more about that in the [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) article.